# How to select radio button and select option with ember integration tests?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

How to select a radio button in and a particular select option with ember integration tests? I know how to use the click one and the fillIn for inputs.

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/testing/test-helpers/

Comment: What is wrong with doing `click()` on the radio button?

Comment: @givanse thx, what about selects?

Answer (score 8):

Radio button:

```
click('css selector');
```

For the `select` say you have:

```
<select>
    <option>red pill</option>
    <option>blue pill</option>
</select>
```

In your test:

```
fillIn('css selector', 'red pill');
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I don't know what a value will be?

Comment: You are doing integration tests, you **must** know. You should be using a sample database/API. Something like Pretender.

Comment: No I can't really on this it's impossible in my case

Comment: Nothing is impossible, specially with software. And it is **contradictory** to have a dynamic environment in your tests suite, bad tests.

Comment: I agree, but for this case it must be dynamic

Comment: Maybe I should just use some sort of jquery javascript to accomplish this. The test code I write must be able to be run against different apps.

Comment: as a caveat to the answer above, I've  found that I've needed to ``fillIn`` the value of the option, which may not necessarily be the text.

Comment: As allready mentioned `fillIn` requires option value if used with select. If you only know the option label like @SuperUberDuper it's a little bit hacky:
`fillIn('css selector', $('css selector option:contains("your label")').val());` Of course option labels should be unique.